# Font Change In Different Devices

Tags: html, css, text, fonts

i use a font in my web page.there is not any problem in chrome and Firefox and IE in my computer but in other Devices the font changes.
Someone knows why this happens?

---

```
*{

font-family: Montserrat;
 }
```

Comment: add your code sample

Comment: @Malik Adil done

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to use a web font but you are not providing the font file. - https://responsivedesign.is/articles/should-i-use-system-fonts-or-web-fonts/ - some where like google fonts is a good place to go if you want to use a web font - https://fonts.google.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font is installed in your system, therefore, it's not changed in your device. you need to add the font in your code.

e.g

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
```

add in the CSS file  change the link with your require font

or if you have a font file then add the font file in the CSS as

```
@font-face { font-family: roboto-regular; 
             src: url('../font/Roboto-Regular.ttf'); } 
h2{
    font-family: roboto-regular;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define your font in your css file.
For Ex:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
  src: url(font-location);
}

* {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that some browsers/OS/Devices doesn't support that font. 
Define multiple fonts.

```
* {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

Another solution can be download Google Web Fonts, upload them with your website and define them in the css files manually. Another way may be usage of JavaScript Web Font Loader instead of the default one.

Answer (score 0):

In your Header:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Caesar+Dressing&display=swap" 
rel="stylesheet">
```

In your CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Caesar+Dressing&display=swap');
.fontn{
  font-family:'Caesar Dressing', cursive;
}
```